# Using multiple keys in AUCTeX LaTeX-math-list

Tags: auctex

`LaTeX-math-mode` in AUCTeX is very convenient for shorcuts. For example, I define the following in my .emacs file:

```lisp
(defconst LaTeX-math-list '(?f "frac")))
```

Then if I type <kbd>`f</kbd> the Emacs buffer displays `\frac{}` which saves a lot of typing.

My question is: is it possible to use multiple keys for shorcuts? I would like to type
<kbd>`ba</kbd>  so that the Emacs buffer displays

```latex
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:}
\end{align}
```

Is this possible using `LaTeX-math-list`?

Similarly I would like to use <kbd>`bs</kbd> so that Emacs displays

```latex
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \end{split}
  \label{eq:}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're better off using `cdlatex` as a minor mode within AUCTeX.  Form the README:

> **OVERVIEW**
>
> CDLaTeX is a minor mode supporting mainly mathematical and scientific
> text development with LaTeX.  CDLaTeX is really about speed.  AUCTeX
> (the major mode I recommend for editing LaTeX files) does have a hook
> based system for inserting environments and macros - but while this is
> useful and general, it is sometimes slow to use.  CDLaTeX tries to be
> quick, with very few and easy to remember keys, and intelligent
> on-the-fly help.

Check the features from [README](https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex) and install it from MELPA if you want to give it a roll.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. CDLaTeX is great :)